# Steps taken to differentiate action in wave equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, action, variational-calculus

I'm currently reading Blundell and Lancaster's "Quantum Field Theory for the Gifted Amateur."

In chapter 1, example 1.4, they talk about how the action and Lagrangian density ideas are super helpful. It goes like:

~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~

Consider a string.

Mass $m$.

Length $l$.

Thus we have a mass density of $l$.

Let $\mathcal{T}$ denote tension.

Let $\psi (x,t)$ be the function that describes the displacement of the rope.

Total kinetic energy is given by the integral $T=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{L} dx\;\rho  \left( \frac{\partial \psi }{\partial t} \right) ^2 $.

And potential by $V=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{l} dx\;\mathcal{T} \left( \frac{\partial \psi }{\partial x} \right) ^2 $.

The action is then

\begin{align*}
 S \left[ \psi (x,y)  \right]   &= \int dt\;L \\
   &= \int dt\;(T-V)\\
   &= \int dt\;dx\;\mathcal{L} \left( \psi ,\frac{\partial \psi }{\partial t},\frac{\partial \psi }{\partial x}  \right)  
\end{align*}

Here, the Lagrangian density is

$$\mathcal{L}\left( \psi ,\frac{\partial \psi }{\partial t},\frac{\partial \psi }{\partial x} \right)=\frac{\rho }{2} \left( \frac{\partial \psi }{\partial t} \right) ^2 -\frac{\mathcal{T}}{2} \left( \frac{\partial \psi }{\partial x} \right) ^2 $$

~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~

**My question:** After that, they proceed to take $\frac{\delta S}{\delta \psi }$ and show that

$$\frac{\delta S}{\delta \psi }=\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \psi }-\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial (\partial \psi /\partial x)}-\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial (\partial \psi /\partial t)}\tag{i}$$

Which then leads to the wave equation. But, how was that result (i) obtained?

**UPDATE:** For anyone reading this question in the future, as shared by Níckolas Alves, [Nivaldo Lemos](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1108416586)' book "Analytical Mechanics" goes through all of this at the beginning of chapter 11. He develops the general picture and then applies it to the wave equation in the first example.

Comment: This isn't an answer because this is not a resource-recommendation post, but if I recall correctly the book Analytical Mechanics, by Nivaldo Lemos, derives that expression when discussing functional derivatives.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, Níckolas!

Comment: You do the same thing as you do in (particle) classical mechanics. Derive the integrand and then integrate by parts with respect to time and space to arrive at the desired result. When you derive the integrand you get the first term automatically, the second term you get by integrating by parts w.r.t. space, and the third w.r.t. time.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Leonid
I had a superficial idea of what to do, but this clears things up.

Answer (score 1):

> Which then leads to the wave equation. But, how was that result (i) obtained?

It is basic multi-variable differential calculus.

See, for example, [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/719412/questions-regarding-the-derivation-of-euler-lagrange-equation-from-taylors-clas/719420#719420), which explains something quite similar.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that! I guess the notation used in different books confused me a bit and made me doubt what I thought I knew.